# How can I increase XML data type in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, import, data-dump

I'm trying to import a large XML data-type in SQL Server 2008, but I'm getting the following error message:

> *Msg 6365, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>
>   An XML operation resulted an XML data type exceeding 2GB in size. Operation aborted.*

Does anyone know what I can do to circumvent this / increase the limit in SQL Server? I finally figured out how to import the `Data.Stackexchange.com` data-dump, but now it's telling me the XML file is too big for the way I'm importing.

using:

```
/* Populate the temp table with the comments.xml file */
INSERT INTO #WorkingTable
SELECT *
FROM   OPENROWSET(BULK 'd:\so\comments.xml',SINGLE_BLOB) AS data
```

If you need any other information lemme know. Thanks!

<sub>found [this site](http://qa.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlxml/thread/b1528694-edf3-40b2-8666-13e0843a5e91), hope it's not the best resource out there...</sub>

**EDIT** Thanks to @Bummi  [it seems this is a restriction in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). **Does anyone know how/if I can get around this?**

Answer (score 3):

It's limited to 2 GB
[Reference Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx)
[SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
[SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: @iight: there is no workaround - it's limited to 2 GB - period.